# Decoding German umlauts in Python: \U+00c4, \U+00d6, and \U+00dc

Tags: python, unicode

My application is getting words with German umlauts in this form:

```
\U+00c4 (this is Ä)
\U+00d6 (this is Ö)
\U+00dc (this is Ü)
```

This format is slightly different from the formats I found on the Internet (see [here](http://graphemica.com/%C3%9C)).

For example, Ü should be `\u00DC` and not `\U+00dc`. I'm able to decode them using `replace()`, but I think this should not be the preferred way:

```
value = '\U+00dc'    
print value.replace('\U+', '\u').decode('unicode-escape').encode('utf-8')
```

This works, but the question is: is there a way to do this without calling `replace()`? (`replace()` is here in fact a workaround)

Comment: 1- I can't reproduce it: `print '\U+00dc'.replace('\U+', '\u').decode('unicode-escape')` produces `Ü` (no errors). Find the minimal input data that produces the error (split in half and test them separately, continue splitting until only several bytes remain that produce  the error) 2- Don't call `.encode('utf-8')`. Always print Unicode. Otherwise you can produce mojibake if the environment uses a different encoding (don't hardcode the character encoding of your environment inside your script).

Comment: Sorry, my question is not clear enough. Yes `print '\U+00dc'.replace('\U+', '\u').decode('unicode-escape')` does work,  but the question is: is there a 'native' python method do to this, without calling replace()? (Question edited)

Comment: what does it mean "native"? You could define a codec if you like that will understand `'\\U+XXXX'` format, the same way `unicode-escape` understands `'\\uxxxx'` format. But it would be an overkill. I would understand if you've asked how to do it without `unicode-escape` codec (something like: `result = re.sub(r'\\U\+(\d{4})', lambda m: unichr(int(m.group(1), 16)), text)`)

Comment: this works: `print re.sub(r'\\U\+([0-9a-z]{4})', lambda m: unichr(int(m.group(1), 16)), '\U+00dc')` -> `Ü`

Comment: Thank you Sebastian. Maybe can you add a answer with your code and some explanations?  What the code exactly does?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Your question has the working (in some cases) code in it already. I've provided another way (you might prefer one or another depending on your specific case). There could be other ways to get the same result. Are there other instances of backslashes in the input other than `\U+`? Do you need to support non-BMP Unicode characters? Is time performance a concern in your case?